# The whole UI gone from the website

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm working on [this](http://toolskaart.com/index.php/) website. Because the client changed some settings the 'index.php' was gone from website and I corrected. From then the whole UI of the website is gone. I tried to do something from the backend and the was wondered to see the backend also gone. It just redirects to the from end once I log-in for back. Are there any solutions for this. Please suggest. I'm in very much need of it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin->system->configuration-> General->Web-> for both Unsecure and secure ->'Base URL' should not end with index.php

Flush the cache after changing the settings.

Comment: If you can't change that settings from website, chenge it from phpmyadmin. table name:  core_config_data. You can easily find web/unsecure/base_url, web/secure/base_url records there

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the worst part. The backend itself is gone. Once I log-in from the backend, it will redirect to website from end.

Comment: That's why I added the comment too. You need to change those variables from mysql. You can find those variables "web/unsecure/base_url, web/secure/base_url" in  'core_config_data' table.

Comment: how to remove it phpmyadmin?

Comment: admin->system->Cache Management-> Select all and refresh. Another way to remove cache is emptying magento/var/cache/ folder

Answer (score 0):

A fewdays back when I was working in my localmachine I faced the same problem. I'm not sure why the UI has gone, But the solution worked for me is:

In server cmd prompt, I have stopped the IP tables by command --  **service iptables stop** and by disabling selinux by command -- **setenforce 0** ... After giving these two commands, clearing the cache , the site came normal. But these cannot be implemented on online servers. Just try with these. If it works then can come to conclusion, that server is fine.